# java.util.PropertyPermission user.home read (Access Denied)

Tags: java, io, applet, signed-applet

I have a signed applet in which i have used JFilechooser to browse file from local file system for uploading. It runs properly in windows and mac. But in linux it shows error *Access Denied (java.util.PropertyPermission user.home read)*. I searched in the internet and found one [solution](http://www.ccp4.ac.uk/jwc/image_applet/Policy_file_examps_ccp4.html). I did accordingly, however could not solve the problem.

I created file .java.policy file inside my home folder.

```
grant codeBase "http://bioinfo.utu.fi/applet/*" {
  permission java.io.FilePermission "/home/raj/-", "read";
  permission java.io.FilePermission "/home/raj/-", "write, delete";
};
```

I could not get JFileChooser dialogue in Linux when i click "Browse" button, but shows Exception: *Access Denied (java.util.PropertyPermission user.home read)*. How can i run it in Linux?
I appreciate your help.

**Recent Update:**

I searched java.policy file from the terminal

```
[raj@localhost Desktop]$ locate java.policy
/home/raj/.java.policy
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0/jre/lib/security/java.policy
```

I added following lines in the file /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0/jre/lib/security/java.policy

```
grant{
    ...
    ...
    permission java.util.PropertyPermission "user.home", "read";
        permission java.io.FilePermission "/home/raj", "read";
    permission java.io.FilePermission "${user.home}${/}*", "read,write";

    }
```

Noe i can see JFileChoose Dialogue. Now i got another problem. I could not see and files on home directory in the applet file chooser dialogue.

Comment: How can i make the browse button work on Linux ?

Comment: So you've solved the question in your title and you now have a different question? Time to close this one.

Answer (score -1):

The problem may be much deeper it seems to...

Have you checked the user.home with not an applet but a local util? Is it **"?"** or something not like an absolute path?

I do recommend you to check it with System.getProperty("user.home") but with a desktop util;

Also there can be a client machine problem as 32-bit JDK . It is a well known [bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6972329) so maybe that is the problem.

Please report that helps

Comment: I tried with desktop application. System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.home")). It shows correct home directory. What i knew is that applet required two permissions java.io.FilePermission and java.util.PropertyPermission. I added both permission in java.policy file. Now i can see the JFileChoose dialogue but could not see nay files on the home directory.

Comment: Emm... are you trying to use user.home as a start point of your jfilechooser? As an alt try to set some different start point; I mean this method http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#setCurrentDirectory%28java.io.File%29 ; please report that helps

Comment: And tell me your linux jre version please

Comment: yes i am trying user.home as starting point of JFileChooser.I have used the same method you mentioned setCurrentDirectory(). My Java version is *java version "1.6.0_20"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.9.10) (fedora-55.1.9.10.fc14-i386)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 19.0-b09, mixed mode)*

Comment: Emm... have you tried to use setCurrentDirectory() for some other location? I mean not for the user.home only?

Comment: And was the applet certificate added to jre trusted certificates storage? Can you see the certificate in the certificates list?

Comment: The problem is the `AccessControlException` reading the property, not the content of the property. Read the question.